# How to pass username in url

Tags: url-rewriting, parameter

I have several author page like

> mysite.com/author/username1
>   mysite.com/author/username2

I want to create a dynamic url like

> mysite.com/author/current_loggedin_username

How to create this.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Currently, it is not clear to me what is going on with this dynamic link.

Comment: @nmr I want to create an author page link in navigation menu bar where the logged in user will get to see all his post. The author page link is  in this format mysite.com/author/{logged_in_username} .I want to pass the username in the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should check if the user is logged in - use [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).
Next step is to get ID of current user with [get_current_user_id()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/).
Next, get the URL for the author with the given ID using [get_author_posts_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_author_posts_url).
The last step is to display the button with the link.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() )
{
    $uid = get_current_user_id();
    $link = get_author_posts_url( $uid );
    printf( '<div><a href="%s">My posts</a></div>', $link );
}
```

You can insert such a code in the `header.php` file or add it as a function to `functions.php` file and call this function in the `header.php`.